# C - conflicting types across .h and .c files

Tags: c

I'm getting an error of `error: conflicting types for 'initList'` with some code I wrote across a .c file and a .h file. Here's the code in the .c file:

```
#include "lists.h"

void initList(LIST* list) {
  list->head.coef = 0;
  list->head.exp = 0;
}
```

And here's the corresponding code in the .h file:

```
#ifndef LISTS_H__
#define LISTS_H__

#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct node {
  int coef;
  int exp;
  struct node* next;
} NODE;

typedef struct list {
  NODE head;
} LIST;

void initList(LIST*);

#endif
```

I really don't understand what I'm doing wrong here... I've checked other similar questions, but none of the solutions their answers suggested work here and/or I already had the fixes in place.

Comment: Are you compiling with a C compiler, or are you using a C++ compiler?

Comment: I'm using MinGW's gcc on Windows.

Comment: What happens if you add the parameter name (list) to the declaration?

Comment: What, precisely, are you trying to do when you get this error? And can you show us the *full* error description?

Comment: There's no such error in the code you posted so far. The types are not conflicting. There must be something you are not showing us.

Comment: @DanielJour: Nothing at all, I still get the error.

@DavidSchwartz: I'm just trying to compile the code. Here's the full error description: `linkedList.c:17:6: error: conflicting types for 'initList'`
`void initList(LIST* list) {`
`lists.h:22:6: note: previous declaration of 'initList' was here`
`NODE head; // first item in list`

@AnT: That's all the code that pertains to the types and functions shown and used; there's a _lot_ of other code, so I refrained from posting it.

Comment: I do not see any error in the code snipped you have provided. I have compiled your code, with .h and the fun def in main, and no errors reported when using gcc or g++. can you provide your full code snippet.

Comment: @Ryan: It is likely that something in `linkedList.c` somehow changes the meaning of `LIST`. But we can't see it from here.

Comment: I think it is clear from the error message that it thinks the variable name list in the function parameter is the name of the structure called list.  Try removing the names of the list structure and just leave it as a typedef of an anonymous structure:  `typedef struct {  NODE head;} LIST;`

Comment: @JerryJeremiah: Thanks, this worked! I didn't even think of this for some reason! @_@

Comment: Try replacing `void initList(LIST*);` with `void initList(LIST* list)`

Comment: @Jerry Jeremiah: That's unrealistic. It could be a side-effect of some other problem (macro-related or something like that), but by itself it is not an issue here. A C compiler will not confuse variable name `list` with a struct tag `list`.

Comment: @AnT I agree but the error message was very clear about `NODE head;` being the first definition of list and he said it worked so it was the right answer.  However I cut and pasted his code verbatim into identically named files and compiled it with no errors using MingW so he *shouldn't* have had any errors at all.  Wierd

Comment: @Jerry Jeremiah: The `NODE head` line is apparently some copy-paste blunder. The compiler was trying to point out the previous declaration of `initList`. It could not have possibly referred to `NODE head` line for that. Again, the presented code is completely problem-free. The root of the problem is in the rest of the code that we can't see. Removal of struct tags can only sweep the problem under the carpet, it does not really fix anything.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, the word list for a variable is not a great choice.  Moving on.

From what I can see it appears that you are making a self-referential structure, though with the head element as a separate structure but of the same structure as the nodes.

Like some of the comments I also did not get any errors with the code that you posted, so to help you out, here is some code that uses what you have to create a list and then add values and link the list and nodes together.  I have also put in a change to the last node using the -> operator.

I hope this helps you out.

In the h file.

```
/*
 *  35352860_list.h
 */

#ifndef _35352860_LIST_H__
#define _35352860_LIST_H__

#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct node
    {
      int coef;
      int exp;
      struct node* next;
    } NODE;

typedef struct list
    {
    NODE head;
    } LIST;

void initList(LIST*);

#endif  /* _35352860_LIST_H__ */
```

And the c file.

```
    /*
 *  35352860_main.c
 */

#include "35352860_list.h"

void initList(LIST* list)
    {
    list->head.coef = 0x0000;
    list->head.exp = 0x0000;
    list->head.next = NULL;
    }


int main
    (
    unsigned int    argc,
    unsigned char   *arg[]
    )
{
    LIST    list;
    NODE    node_1;
    NODE    node_2;

    printf("There is 1 variable of type LIST and 2 variable of type NODE.\n");
    printf("Address of list................................0x%.8X\n", &list);
    printf("Value of list.head.coef........................0x%.8X\n", list.head.coef);
    printf("Value of list.head.exp.........................0x%.8X\n", list.head.exp);
    printf("Value of list.head.next........................0x%.8X\n", list.head.next);
    printf("The nodes                                                Node_1      Node_2\n");
    printf("Address of nodes.........................................0x%.8X  0x%.8X\n", &node_1, &node_2);
    printf("Value of nodes.coef......................................0x%.8X  0x%.8X\n", node_1.coef, node_2.coef);
    printf("Value of nodes.exp.......................................0x%.8X  0x%.8X\n", node_1.exp, node_2.exp);
    printf("Value of nodes.next......................................0x%.8X  0x%.8X\n", node_1.next, node_2.next);
    printf("\n\nCall initList.\n");
    initList(&list);
    printf("Address of list.head...........................0x%.8X\n", &list);
    printf("Value of list.head.coef........................0x%.8X\n", list.head.coef);
    printf("Value of list.head.exp.........................0x%.8X\n", list.head.exp);
    printf("Value of list.head.next........................0x%.8X\n", list.head.next);
    printf("The nodes                                                Node_1      Node_2\n");
    printf("Address of nodes.........................................0x%.8X  0x%.8X\n", &node_1, &node_2);
    printf("Value of nodes.coef......................................0x%.8X  0x%.8X\n", node_1.coef, node_2.coef);
    printf("Value of nodes.exp.......................................0x%.8X  0x%.8X\n", node_1.exp, node_2.exp);
    printf("Value of nodes.next......................................0x%.8X  0x%.8X\n", node_1.next, node_2.next);
    printf("\n\nLinking node_1 to list, and add some values to node_1.\n");
    list.head.next = &node_1;
    node_1.coef = 0x1111;
    node_1.exp = 0x1111;
    node_1.next = NULL;
    printf("Address of list.head...........................0x%.8X\n", &list);
    printf("Value of list.head.coef........................0x%.8X\n", list.head.coef);
    printf("Value of list.head.exp.........................0x%.8X\n", list.head.exp);
    printf("Value of list.head.next........................0x%.8X\n", list.head.next);
    printf("The nodes                                                Node_1      Node_2\n");
    printf("Address of nodes.........................................0x%.8X  0x%.8X\n", &node_1, &node_2);
    printf("Value of nodes.coef......................................0x%.8X  0x%.8X\n", node_1.coef, node_2.coef);
    printf("Value of nodes.exp.......................................0x%.8X  0x%.8X\n", node_1.exp, node_2.exp);
    printf("Value of nodes.next......................................0x%.8X  0x%.8X\n", node_1.next, node_2.next);
    printf("\n\nLinking node_2 to node_1, and add some values to node_2.\n");
    node_1.next = &node_2;
    node_2.coef = 0x2222;
    node_2.exp = 0x2222;
    node_2.next = NULL;
    printf("Address of list.head...........................0x%.8X\n", &list);
    printf("Value of list.head.coef........................0x%.8X\n", list.head.coef);
    printf("Value of list.head.exp.........................0x%.8X\n", list.head.exp);
    printf("Value of list.head.next........................0x%.8X\n", list.head.next);
    printf("The nodes                                                Node_1      Node_2\n");
    printf("Address of nodes.........................................0x%.8X  0x%.8X\n", &node_1, &node_2);
    printf("Value of nodes.coef......................................0x%.8X  0x%.8X\n", node_1.coef, node_2.coef);
    printf("Value of nodes.exp.......................................0x%.8X  0x%.8X\n", node_1.exp, node_2.exp);
    printf("Value of nodes.next......................................0x%.8X  0x%.8X\n", node_1.next, node_2.next);
    printf("\n\nChange the value node_2.coef using the -> operator.\n");
    list.head.next -> next -> coef = 0x3333;
    printf("Address of list.head...........................0x%.8X\n", &list);
    printf("Value of list.head.coef........................0x%.8X\n", list.head.coef);
    printf("Value of list.head.exp.........................0x%.8X\n", list.head.exp);
    printf("Value of list.head.next........................0x%.8X\n", list.head.next);
    printf("The nodes                                                Node_1      Node_2\n");
    printf("Address of nodes.........................................0x%.8X  0x%.8X\n", &node_1, &node_2);
    printf("Value of nodes.coef......................................0x%.8X  0x%.8X\n", node_1.coef, node_2.coef);
    printf("Value of nodes.exp.......................................0x%.8X  0x%.8X\n", node_1.exp, node_2.exp);
    printf("Value of nodes.next......................................0x%.8X  0x%.8X\n", node_1.next, node_2.next);

    return(0x0000);
}
```